# Как сделать фильтр на продуктов на laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Проблемма вот такая.
Есть у меня интернет магазин на Laravel 5.8.
Мне там нужно сделать поиск из фильтрацией.
Что уже сделано:
1) Есть форма на фронтенде, которая принимает запрос. Выдачу массива товара после поиска по слову регулирует такой класс

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Products;

public function search(){
$search = request()->query('search');
if($search){
            $products =
             Products::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->get();
             /*на самом деле тут еще много кода до того как генерируется $products, но я укоротил, оставив самое основное*/
} else {
            $products = [];
        }
return view('myview')->with('products', $products);
```

Все работает хорошо, но я сталкивиюсь с проблеммой когда потом хочу фильтровать результаты поиска.
Для фильтрации у меня стоит другая форма которая использует другой Route::
Для фильтрации в этом же контроллере использую такой клас ( сверху request, products подключен, не буду дублировать).

```html
public function filter(Request $request)
    { 
      /*не понимаю как тут сделать всю логику*/

       return view('myview')->with('products', $products);
     }
```

Второй клас на выходе мне должен возвращать уже отфильтрованные продукты.
Не знаю как это сделать.
С какими я проблеммами столкнулся.
1) После поиска в URL получаю такую строку /search?search=product1 ( я искал по имени product1) Я хочу чтобы после приминения фильтра по цене в URL уже была такая строка /search?search=product1/filter?minprice=0&maxprice=100 ( тут максимальная цена 100)
Не понимаю как это сделать
2) После того как отрабатывает клас фильтра то весь массив сформирован в предидущем классе исчезает. Как сохранить результаты поиска и передать в сделующий клас?

Comment: Почему не сделаете по тому же принципу, что и поиск? 
$search = request()->query('search');
$filterValue = request()->query('filter');
Products::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->where('filterArea', $filterValue)->get();

Comment: Я не хочу целый код переписывать из предидущего метода, так как там у меня код длинее намного. Там у меня 3 массива, они формируются в один и так далее.
Хотелось бы взять перенести эту всю логику вместе из параметрами в другой метод и там же обработать.

Comment: Вам не хватает понимания: 1. Структуры URL. То, что вы хотите сделать с адресом не слишком укладывается в рамки нормальности и общепринятого хорошего стиля; 2. Нормального цикла жизни php-скрипта. Между двумя загрузками формы никакой код не передаётся. Вам придётся сохранить строку поиска в URL, в cookies или сессии. И когда срабатывает фильтр вам нужно заново искать в базе все записи соответствующие строке product1. Нормальным решением будет добавить функционал фильтрации прямо в форму и класс поиска. В вашем случае поиск и фильтр - это один и тот же механизм выбора из БД.

Comment: Для повторного использования уже готового класса, мб стоит обратиться к наследованию классов?